# Error in Loading SQLSERVER Driver in jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am using SQLSERVER 2008 R2
While loading SQLServer Driver in jdbc using statement

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
```

I am getting error with

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at ConnectMSSQL.main(ConnectMSSQL.java:19)
```

I also set sqljdbc4.jar file in classpath but still getting same error, please help guys, my task is almost in delay.

Comment: How did you set your classpath?

Comment: my classpath is right , actually driver-name i provided was wrong. now it's working. Thanks a lot guys for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

As per the following mentioned sit:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/b425c201-9882-4a48-b049-4004f202b0c6

you need to set the path of the jar file into your classpath. For more details please visit the above mentioned site.